# Minimize form in Firemonkey application

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe3

I use this:

```
Application.Minimize;
```

in Vcl delphi application, but in Firemonkey I've got *Undeclared identifire* error.

How can I minimize my firemonkey form?

Comment: Which version of FMX?

Comment: Sorry I'm new to delphi, I use Rad Studio XE3 and Firemonkey Desktop application in default

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using the [`WindowState`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/FMX.Forms.TCommonCustomForm.WindowState) property like so

```
WindowState := TWindowState.wsMinimized;
```