# Maximizing fast report at run time in firemonkey application

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, firemonkey, firemonkey-fm3

How to maximize the fast report at run time in firemonkey application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [`WindowState := wsMaximized;`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Forms.TCommonCustomForm.WindowState).

> Represents how the form appears on the screen.
>   Set WindowState to minimize, maximize, or restore the form window. Read WindowState to determine whether the form is minimized, maximized, or in a normal state.
>   Possible values for the WindowState property are:
>
> - wsMaximized
> - wsMinimized
> - wsNormal

See also [`Minimize form in Firemonkey application`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15198531/576719).